# PHP/ read from folder

Tags: php

I have the next code:

```
<?php 
    $path = 'imgsFor';
    $files_array = scandir($path);
    for ($x=0; $x<=4; $x++)
    {
    echo '<img src="imgsFor/$files_array[$x]"   <br>';
  }
?>
```

In order to display all images in the folder imgsFor.

For some reason, I see the just boxes and not the actual images.

What can be the reason?

Comment: The reason is that you're using single-quotes instead of double-quotes, so the the literal string `imgsFor/$files_array[$x]` will be used instead of the actual variable value. Use double-quotes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up some things. Your correct script would be

```
<?php 

$path = 'imgsFor/';
$files_array = scandir($path);
foreach($files_array as $f) {
    if(is_dir($path . $f) === false)
        continue;

    echo '<img src="' , $path , $f , '"><br>';
}

/* EOF */
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way for me is to use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) function:

```
foreach (glob($path) as $filename) {
    echo '<img src="' . $path . '/' . $filename . '"/><br/>';
}
```

Comment: Just asking: What's the advantage of using `glob()` if you simply want to iterate over all files in a folder? For patterns (something like `*.txt`) `glob()` is perfect but is it not an overkill for a simple path?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER You're right - better is to use `scandir` with `is_dir`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your URL is invalid. Your variable wont echo out if you use single quotes. You also forgot to end the tag. Try this:

```
 echo "<img src='http://yourwebsite.com/imgsFor/{$files_array[$x]}'/><br/>";
```

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: they are valid even if using STRICT doctype.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: [Says who?](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Please check you directory path and use is_dir which returns false when the file doesn't exist. you can try like this

```
$path = 'imgsFor';

$scan = scandir($path);

foreach($scan as $file)
{
    if (!is_dir($path))
    {
        echo $file.'\n';
    }
}
```