# Permission denied on fopen

Tags: php

I get a Permission denied  when I use `fopen` to the folder in WAMP server on Windows :

```
# open file to write
$fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');

# start curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

# set return transfer to false
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

# increase timeout to download big file
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 );

# write data to local file
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );

# execute curl
curl_exec( $ch );

# close curl
curl_close( $ch );

# close local file
fclose( $fp );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the FAQ to see how to format a question properly in order to get the best response from the community. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Please provide proper details and put your questions in a proper format understandable for others.

Comment: did you tried or die()  to get the error?

Comment: without die or try @demonofnight

Comment: what is your path?, it is inside the WAMP folder?

Comment: Is your folder as read-only?

Comment: you are using fopen for directory please use for file. please  create file in DiwanOnline folder like below example

Comment: what the result must appear here @SirajKhan

Comment: you can save file using curl by this code .Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this, i have checked on WAMP, Hope this should work for you.

Create file in **DiwanOnline** folder and use like this ..

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\DiwanOnline\\testfile.txt";
# open file to write
$fh = fopen($path,'w');
$URL="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240205/i-have-a-permission-denied-proplem-when-i-excecute-php-fopen-to-the-folder-in-wa#20240205";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fh);
```

**Warning: fopen(C:/wamp/www/DiwanOnline)** [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\DiwanOnline\Diwan\downLoadDiwanOnLine.php on line 59 Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in C:\wamp\www\DiwanOnline\Diwan\downLoadDiwanOnLine.php on line 72 Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\wamp\www\DiwanOnline\Diwan\downLoadDiwanOnLine.php on line 75

ahh ... you tried to **open folder instead of file**

Please fix it

Comment: yet Permission denied @Siraj Khan

Comment: Can you please share exact error message with us so that we can sort out the issue

Comment: Warning: fopen(C:/wamp/www/DiwanOnline) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\DiwanOnline\Diwan\downLoadDiwanOnLine.php on line 59

Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in C:\wamp\www\DiwanOnline\Diwan\downLoadDiwanOnLine.php on line 72

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\wamp\www\DiwanOnline\Diwan\downLoadDiwanOnLine.php on line 75@Siraj Khan

Comment: Please change permissions and put on www folder "everybody" for "full control" and also check the firewall

Comment: i make it permission but stay permission denied , what i can do on firewall setting @Siraj Khan

Comment: what , how i would take file from directory, but i cant

Comment: you can use scandir  for read files. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219481/php-read-from-folder/20219684#20219684

Comment: Yes , right he became right , but the file is empty , why @Siraj Khan